# [Python]-Can not determine variable type by assigning a value to it using a input() func, why?

Tags: python, variables, input, visual-studio-code, types

I’m assigning a numerical value to a variable called `code` using the `input()` function in the terminal. Below are my lines of code:

```
code = input("Please enter your code:\n")

print(code)
print("\n")
print(type(code))
```

my question though is that, why after doing so I wouldn’t be able to determine the type of my variable called `code`, using this line of code `print(type(code))`. My interpreter in VS Code would give me back this error:

```
Please enter your code:
2
Unable to find thread for evaluation.
```

Is there something wrong with my debugger settings or Debug Console? or something that I’m missing? I’m pretty new to all of this, so please explain in simple terms. Thanks a lot.

---

PS. I've set my console to "internalConsole", maybe that's what is causing this !?

Comment: I think the problem occurred before `print("\n")`, not `print(type(code))`.

Comment: Because `print(...)` prints new-line at the end by default.

Comment: @BoseongChoi Thanks for your comment, but I've tried and removed the `print("\n")` line, but still would get the same error. !

Comment: I get the result `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Have you tried using the integrated console?